# STL Heap with Node pointers

Tags: c++, stl

I have a Node class with the members

```
int weight;
Node *left;
Node *right;
```

I want to create a heap by using the STL functions

```
make_heap(Iterator , Iterator, comp) 
pop_heap(Iterator, Iterator, comp)
```

to apply on a vector of Node pointers. How can I create a comparison object (or comparison function) for those functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide strict weak ordering via a `operator<` for your object you can call the overload of `make_heap`, `pop_heap`, etc which don't even need the third argument. `comp` is so you can provide a custom comparison if you choose.

```
class Node
{
int weight;
Node *left;
Node *right;

public:
bool operator<(const Node& rhs) const { return weight < rhs.weight; }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
struct node_comparison : public std::binary_function< const Node*, const Node*, bool > 
{
    bool operator()( const Node* const a, const Node* const b ) const 
    {
        return a->weight < b->weight;
    }
};
```

Note that this comparsion object compares *only* the weights, but I assume this is desired behaviour.

Comment: That syntax looks wrong: `std::binary_function< void, const Node*, const Node* >` should be `std::binary_function<const Node*, const Node*, bool>` actually better yet use references.